# Django Admin, Collapsable text boxes

Tags: python, django

[image]

How do I get these Textboxes to be collapsible?
I went through the documentation and this is what I wrote, but the changes are not being reflected.

Also, Is there any alternative I can use instead of limiting the user to select a max of 2 project manager or testers or what ever user they want to specify?
(Is there a way such that, the user can click on a + button or something so that another user can be listed is what I mean)

```
   class FlatPageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       fieldsets = (
           (None, {
               'fields': ('Project_Name',
                'Project_Description',
                 'Admin_Name',
                'Admin_Mail_ID',
                'Project_Manager_1',
                'Project_Manager_1_Mail_ID',
                 'Technician_1',
                'Technician_1_Mail_ID',
                'Tester_1',
                'Tester_1_Mail_ID',
                 'Status_of_the_project',
                 'Created',
                 'Finish_Date',
                 'Supporting_Documents',
)
           }),
           ('Add More Users', {
               'classes': ('collapse',),
               'fields': ('Project_Manager_2',
'Project_Manager_2_Mail_ID',
'Technician_2',
'Technician_2_Mail_ID',
'Technician_3',
'Technician_3_Mail_ID',
'Additional_User_1',
'Additional_User_1_Type',
'Additional_User_1_Mail_ID',
'Additional_User_2',
'Additional_User_2_Type',
'Additional_User_2_Mail_ID',
'Additional_User_3',
'Additional_User_3_Type',
'Additional_User_3_Mail_ID',
),
           }),
       )
```

Below is exactly how I wrote my codes for the models.py

```
   Project_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Project_Description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Admin_Name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Admin_Name_users+')
   Admin_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
   Project_Manager_1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Project_Manager_1_users+')
   Project_Manager_1_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
   Project_Manager_2 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Project_Manager_2_users+', blank=True, null=True)
   Project_Manager_2_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Technician_1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Technician_1_users+')
   Technician_1_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
   Technician_2 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Technician_2_users+', blank=True, null=True)
   Technician_2_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Technician_3 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Technician_3_users+', blank=True, null=True)
   Technician_3_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Tester_1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Tester_1_users+')
   Tester_1_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, default='Example@gmail.com')
   Additional_User_1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Ad_1_users+', blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_1_Type = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_1_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_2 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Ad_1_users+', blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_2_Type = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_2_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_3 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Ad_1_users+', blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_3_Type = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_3_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Status_of_the_project = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE_1)
   Created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
   Finish_Date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
   Supporting_Documents = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Django feature that you're looking for is called [Inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects).